# Make 4 responsive box in bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am trying to make this but my forth box goes to the bottom  Here is my code.
Please help me to figure it out. Thanks everyone in advance.

```
<div class="offer">
<h2>Current Offers</h2>
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail checkout-thumbnail">
        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="Image 1">
        <div class="caption checkout-caption">
          <h3>House and Land Packages</h3>

          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-checkout btn-orange" role="button">Check out Button</a> 
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail checkout-thumbnail">
        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="...">
        <div class="caption checkout-caption">
          <h3>House and Land Packages</h3>

          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-checkout btn-teal" role="button">Check out Button</a> 
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail checkout-thumbnail">
        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="...">
        <div class="caption checkout-caption">
          <h3>House and Land Packages</h3>

          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-checkout btn-red" role="button">Check out Button</a> 
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail checkout-thumbnail">
        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="...">
        <div class="caption checkout-caption">
          <h3>House and Land Packages</h3>

          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-checkout btn-red" role="button">Check out Button</a> 
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

and CSS

```
.thumbnail.checkout-thumbnail {
  background: #eee;
  border:none;
  max-width: 220px;

}
.caption.checkout-caption {
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.btn.btn-checkout {
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.btn.btn-orange {
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
.btn.btn-teal {
  border: 2px solid teal;
}
.btn.btn-red {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Please see the image here so that you can understand, I am trying to make it like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Jwmg.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Your Code is working fine. Are you testing your code in small size screen (max 768px) or medium screen (min 769 and max 992). I have tested your code is in small screen and it is working fine. As you have divided 12 column into four `col-sm-3`.

But when it comes to medium screen you have divided your 12 column into only three `col-md-4`. According to your coding the fourth column definitely will go down in medium size screen. So If you want to maintain four columns in medium screen then you have to change your  `col-md-4` to `col-md-3`.

Answer (score 0):

as i can see in you html code you have used `col-md-4` instead of `col-md-3`,
i hope this resolves your query.

As you know bootstrap grid is of 12 columns so you have to use `col-md-3` to get 4 columns in a row.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
col-md-3
```

instead of

```
col-md-4
```

to show all four box in one row for Desktops having width ≥992px